# find .sql and .sql.gz files using find command

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a shell script code which find `.sql.gz` files and moves them:

```
find $Dir -type f -mtime $Time -name \*sql.gz | while read file
do
    echo "Earlier $file will be moved to different folder." >> $Path_Log_File
    mv -f $file $Path_Folder
done
```

Now I have few more files with the extension `.sql` so how can I modify my above code so it includes this file extension as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find offers an "or" (-o) operator:

```
find $Path_Backup_Dir -type f -mtime $Time \( -name \*sql.gz -o -name \*.sql \)
```

The default operator between expressions is "and" (-a).  Since "and" has higher priority than "or", we need to use parens to group the two "-name" expressions together to get the right logic.  Because shells typically treat parens specially, I have escaped them with a backslash to protect them.

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression:

```
find $Path_Backup_Dir -type f -mtime $Time -regex '.*\.(sql|sql.gz)'
```

You should also note that your find/read command pipeline won't respond well to files with special names (leading space trailing spaces, newlines, etc.).  See, for example, [this wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for ways to hand that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the "-or" operator :

```
#Find and Move backup files older than the time constraint defined
find $Path_Backup_Dir -type f -mtime $Time \( -name *sql.gz -or -name *sql \) | while read file
do
    echo "Earlier Backup $file will be moved to archive folder." >> $Path_Log_File
    mv -f $file $Path_Mysql_Archive
done
```

You can do all with a single command:

```
find $Path_Backup_Dir -type f \( -name *.sql -or -name *.sql.gz \) -exec mv -f -v {} /tmp/test2 \; >> $Path_Log_File
```

Comment: It gives error: `find: paths must precede expression: 01-09-2013.tar.gz
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: Do you have space characters in your path ? Escape them '\ ' or use double quote, find "$Path_Backup_Dir"

Comment: no there is no space character it's like `/backup/dump/database/11-12-2013.sql` for example.